# Implementing DAO Factory

Tags: java, abstract-factory

I'm trying to do three different type of DAOs with 4 subtypes of each.  I have RAM, SQL and Serial with each one have four subtypes.

Is a singleton necessary with my implementation within the factory and more specifically with each DAO? Should I use static methods instead? Also I have two factories, is that necessary?

I might be missing the point here of the factory and implementing incorrectly? I only posted RAM and `RAMUser` with RAM Factory and DAO factory, I figure that's all really need to be post.

```
//Abstract class DAO Factory
public abstract class DAOFactory
{
    private static Logger   log = LOG.PRODUCTION;

    public abstract GenericDAO<Trade, String, Boolean> getTradeDAO();

    public abstract GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> getUserDAO();

    public abstract GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> getLogDAO();

    public abstract GenericDAO<ServiceRequest, String, Boolean> getRequestDAO();

    private static DAOFactoryType   currentUsedStorage;

    /**
     * @return the currentUsedStorage
     */
    public static DAOFactoryType getCurrentUsedStorage()
        {
            return currentUsedStorage;
        }

    /**
     * @param currentUsedStorage
     *            the currentUsedStorage to set
     */
    public void setCurrentUsedStorage(DAOFactoryType currentUsedStorage)
        {
            DAOFactory.currentUsedStorage = currentUsedStorage;
        }

    public static DAOFactory getDAOFactory(DAOFactoryType factoryType)
        {
            switch (factoryType)
            {
                case SQL :
                    currentUsedStorage = DAOFactoryType.SQL;
                    return new SQLDAOFactory();
                case RAM :
                    currentUsedStorage = DAOFactoryType.RAM;
                    return new RAMDAOFactory();
                case SERIAL :
                    currentUsedStorage = DAOFactoryType.SERIAL;
                    return new SerialDAOFactory();

                default :
                    return null;
            }
        }
}
```

**`GenericDAO`**

```
public interface GenericDAO<U,S,B>
{
    public boolean update(U user, B active) throws NullUserException,
            UserExistException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
            ReceivedNullParameterException;

    public boolean delete(U user, B active) throws NullUserException,
            UserExistException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
            ReceivedNullParameterException;

    public U findUserByUserName(S userName, B active)
            throws NullUserException, UserExistException, NullListException,
            UserInstanceException, ReceivedNullParameterException;

    public U findUserByUser(U user, B active)
            throws NullUserException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
            ReceivedNullParameterException;

    public boolean insert(U user, B active)
            throws ReceivedNullParameterException, UserExistException,
            NullListException, UserInstanceException;
}
```

**`RAMDAOFactory`**

```
    public class RAMDAOFactory extends DAOFactory
    {
        private static Logger log = LOG.PRODUCTION;

        @Override
        public GenericDAO<Trade, String, Boolean> getTradeDAO()
            {
                return RAMTradeDAO.getRAMTradeDAO();
            }

        @Override
        public GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> getUserDAO()
            {
                return RAMUserDAO.getRAMUserDAO();
            }

        @Override
        public GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> getLogDAO()
            {
                return RAMLogDAO.getRAMLogDAO();
            }

        @Override
        public GenericDAO<ServiceRequest, String, Boolean> getRequestDAO()
            {
                return RAMServiceRequestDAO.getRAMRequestDAO();
            }

    }
```

**`RAMUserDAO`**

```
public class RAMUserDAO implements GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean>
{

    private static RAMUserDAO   userDAO = new RAMUserDAO();
    private Map<String, User>   userList;
    private Map<String, User>   banList;
    private static Logger     log       = LOG.PRODUCTION;

    private RAMUserDAO()
        {
            userList = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, User>();
            banList = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, User>();
        }

    public static RAMUserDAO getRAMUserDAO()
        {
            return userDAO;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean update(User user, Boolean active) throws NullUserException,
            UserExistException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
            ReceivedNullParameterException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(User user, Boolean active) throws NullUserException,
            UserExistException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
            ReceivedNullParameterException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public User findUserByUserName(String userName, Boolean active)
            throws NullUserException, UserExistException, NullListException,
            UserInstanceException, ReceivedNullParameterException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public User findUserByUser(User user, Boolean active)
            throws NullUserException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
            ReceivedNullParameterException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(User user, Boolean active)
            throws ReceivedNullParameterException, UserExistException,
            NullListException, UserInstanceException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: The very existence of `currentUsedStorage` is a bad idea. A global field which you can set, but which also gets set accidentally (`getDAOFactory`), what can it be used for. Imagine a multithreaded program...

Answer (score 1):

> I might be missing the point here of the factory and implementing incorrectly?

[Factories](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) are an abstraction for how to obtain instances, as distinct from explicitly pooling, singletonning, or creating instances (through constructors) from client code.  Exactly how far into this abstraction you want to go is a matter of debate and, in some cases, [ridicule](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12), but this base abstraction is what you need to keep in mind when designing them.

Because factories are a means to an end, it's hard to tell whether your factory will be helpful without seeing your use case.  What will your use of the pattern help you accomplish?  (As a hunch, I'd recommend you to look into [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).)

> Is a singleton necessary with my implementation within the factory and more specifically with each DAO?

No.  A singleton is never really *necessary* anywhere<sup>(1)</sup> and it's usually a convenience hack to prevent having to pass a reference into a method or store it in context; a bypass of sorts.  That's not to say that singletons serve no useful purpose, but that the decision to use a singleton should be an implementation choice, and never a design choice.

<sub>(1) It can even be downright hazardous in server environments with managed containers.</sub>

> The setCurrentUsedStorage is what kind of storage I'm using. So RAM, SQL or Serial implementation. How do you suggest to deal with this?

Ideally, remove the field.  If you have a clear and compelling use case that can not be reasonably solved otherwise, keep the field for now, but clearly document the why and the how (and use the `HACK` pseudo-tag), and consider adding it to your project's to-do list.  This really feels like a bug waiting to happen.

It should not be a factory's duty to *keep track of* what type you are currently interested in.  Either the container (configuration) or the client code should know what it wants/needs (and pass it into the factory method): factories are middle men.

---

That's for the abstract part; let's get to concrete suggestions.

## Pull singletons up to the factory level

The concern of the DAO implementations is data storage and retrieval.  The concern of the factory is how to supply instances.  Lifting the singletons from the individual implementations leaves the factory in control of instantiation and life cycle.

Here's a straightforward example of such an approach:

```
// I like that boilerplate.  That's some nice boilerplate.
public class SimpleStoringFactory extends DAOFactory {
  private final GenericDAO<Trade, String, Boolean> tradeDAO;
  private final GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> userDAO;
  private final GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> logDAO;
  private final GenericDAO<ServiceRequest, String, Boolean> requestDAO;

  public SimpleStoringFactory(
      GenericDAO<Trade, String, Boolean> tradeDAO,
      GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> userDAO,
      GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> logDAO,
      GenericDAO<ServiceRequest, String, Boolean> requestDAO) {
    this.tradeDAO = tradeDAO;
    this.userDAO = userDAO;
    this.logDAO = logDAO;
    this.requestDAO = requestDAO;
  }

  public GenericDAO<Trade, String, Boolean> getTradeDAO() { return tradeDAO; }
  public GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> getUserDAO() { return userDAO; }
  public GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean> getLogDAO() { return logDAO; }
  public GenericDAO<ServiceRequest, String, Boolean> getRequestDAO() { return requestDAO; }
}
```

## `GenericDAO`

```
public boolean update(U user, B active) throws NullUserException,
        UserExistException, NullListException, UserInstanceException,
        ReceivedNullParameterException;
```

That's... quite something.  Only list exceptions that you expect clients to handle/catch, and see whether built-in, available exception types like `IllegalArgumentException` suffice.

If this is not feasible, document when exceptions are expected to be thrown, and when the return value is true or false.  I could not make this out from the method signature.  Compare with:

```
/**
 * Finds the record identified by <var>user</var> and updates it to the given values.
 * Returns true if changes were made to the record, and false if the record was found,
 * but all current values matched given values (i.e. no update occurred).
 *
 * @return {@code true} iff changes were made to the record.
 * @throws NotFoundException if no record for this user was found.
 */
public boolean update(U user, B active) throws NotFoundException;
```

## Documentation

Auto-generated getter and setter comments are not useful as documentation: they simply repeat the name of the function.  Remove these to reclaim some vertical space.

Document what things like `active` mean in your method parameters.  Does it make sense ever not to pass a boolean in there?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a lot to take in at once. I will digest and get back to you. The setCurrentUsedStorage is what kind of storage I'm using. So RAM, SQL or Serial implementation. How do you suggest to deal with this?

Comment: Not sure how I still able to implement RAMUserDAO and RAMTradeDAO and etc...?

Comment: @user3590149 I am not sure how any of this would interfere with that implementation. :s

Comment: I'm not sure how I instantiate it using your factory. So I would just make a new RAMUserDAO, RAMTradeDAO, RAMLogDAO, etc... object and then past it in your SimpleStoringFactory constructor and then call the getters?

Comment: I guess I could pass those objects in the DAOFactory in the first factory?

Comment: @user3590149 I edited the answer w.r.t. `setCurrentUsedStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is one glaring issue with this code:

> - *RAM* **Trade** DAO,
>     *RAM* **User** DAO,
>     *RAM* **Log** DAO,
>     *RAM* **Request** DAO
> - *SQL* **Trade** DAO,
>     *SQL* **User** DAO,
>     *SQL* **Log** DAO,
>     *SQL* **Request** DAO
> - *Serial* **Trade** DAO,
>     *Serial* **User** DAO,
>     *Serial* **Log** DAO,
>     *Serial* **Request** DAO

In rows, I am seeing repetition of persistence type. In columns, I am seeing repetition of business object type. That means that, given `n` persistence types and `m` business object types, there will need to be `n*m` classes. But these two types are not related! They are dealing with two *different* levels of abstraction. Your use of `GenericDAO<U, S, B>` obscures the nature of the different types, making the code more confusing. We should break these apart, and use composition to create the combinations. (*Pseudocode follows*)

```
interface DAO {
    insert(<Supertype of all types> user, Boolean active);
    update(<Supertype of all types> user, Boolean active);
    findByUserName(String user, Boolean active);
    findByUser(<Supertype of all types> user, Boolean active);
    delete(<Supertype of all types> user, Boolean active);
}
```

And classes `RAMDAO`, `SQLDAO`, and `SerialDAO` implement the `DAO` interface.

```
interface Repo<T> {
    setDAO(DAO dao);
    insert(T user, Boolean active);
    update(T user, Boolean active);
    findByUserName(String user, Boolean active);
    findByUser(T user, Boolean active);
    delete(T user, Boolean active);
}
```

And classes `TradeRepo`, `UserRepo`, `LogRepo`, and `RequestRepo` implement the `Repo` interface. Notice the `setDAO` method on `Repo`. We can *inject* the `DAO` we want to use, without depending on what type of persistence the `DAO` object uses. You can also inject the `DAO` in the constructor and leave off the setter if you would rather do it that way.

We now have 2 groups of objects, `n` persistence types, and `m` business object types, and `n+m` classes (plus two interfaces). Most importantly, if I add another, say, persistence type, I only need to create **one** more class, not **`m`** more classes.

---

Now we've broken up the coupling between the classes, meaning now we have to address the factory. Here, you are using a concrete factory to create abstract factory objects, based on type of storage. Instead, we can attack it from a different angle. We need to create two different types of object, and compose them together. They have the same lifetime, and one depends on the other, so we can put them together into the same factory.

```
class RepoFactory {
    RepoFactory(DAOType daoType) {
        this.daoType = daoType;
    }

    getRepoInstance(RepoType repoType) {
        DAO dao;
        switch(daoType) {
            case RAM: dao = new RAMDAO();
            case SQL: dao = new SQLDAO();
            case Serial: dao = new SerialDAO();
        }

        Repo repo;
        switch(repoType) {
            case Trade: repo = new TradeRepo();
            case User: repo = new UserRepo();
            case Log: repo = new LogRepo();
            case Request: repo = new RequestRepo();
        }

        repo.setDAO(dao);
        return repo;
    }
}
```

`RepoFactory` is now instantiable, and you can create different `Repo`s with different `DAOType`s without having to track a global state. This also eliminates the abstract factories, as our objects can now be created inline. We could also trivially instantiate one or both parts as singletons, *independently*. Singletons are not necessary for the most part. The only concern here is whether each persistence type allows multiple connections, and what concurrency issues arise out of singleton-vs-non-singleton. Documentation of the underlying implementations and testing are your friends here.

This code is essentially effective at what it is trying to accomplish. We could leave it as it is. One thing I see, though, is that different parts of the `getRepoInstance` method change at different rates, namely the `DAO` part and the `Repo` part. We are probably more likely to add `Repo`s than to add `DAO`s. Were it me, and I had a few minutes, I would inject a `DAOFactory` instead of a `DAOType` enum, and let the factory produce my `DAO`s. This is optional if you are willing to live with the maintenance overhead, though.

---

You have a lot of generics being tossed around here.

```
GenericDAO<Trade, String, Boolean>
GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean>
GenericDAO<User, String, Boolean>
GenericDAO<ServiceRequest, String, Boolean>
```

First, the last two seem to *always* be `String` and `Boolean`. If these are not going to change, you should leave them off, and just use the concrete types in your implementation. Making these variable just adds complexity and noise to the code, for little gain if they are not actually variable.

Second, `Trade`, `User`, and `ServiceRequest` seem like very different things to me. I don't see the rest of your app, so maybe they are more related than they seems, but the names do not indicate this is so. Indeed, the fact that you are passing them as generic arguments supports the idea that they are not related, otherwise you would just use a supertype. If they are similar in some way, you should encapsulate that similarity in an interface that they all implement. You can then use the interface type to handle these different objects in a similar, type-safe way.

If you followed my suggestions above, the generics don't even exist any more, but in the `DAO` interface, I have a stub type (`<Supertype of all types>`). This would be the interface type.

---

I have to agree with [JvR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59836/38383) regarding the excessive number of exceptions that could be thrown. Looking at them, several of them seem to even *mean* the same thing. Try to wrap them into a single, meaningful exception type for each actual type of error.

---

Like all code, factories should generally strive to be SOLID, but being open/closed can be a little tricky. Here is an article that talks about several different strategies to make factories more open/closed: http://java.globinch.com/patterns/design-patterns/factory-design-patterns-and-open-closed-principle-ocp-in-solid/ It talks about different techniques to make factories more or less abstract, with different trade-offs, and gives code samples to visually show what the code might look like.

Comment: How do you deal with the different types of commands that each storage would implement?  This is why I'm breaking it up with SQL and RAM and Serial. For example the insert command will be different for SQL and for Serial so having one User repo won't work because I have different code for each. One is SQL commands and the other one does I/O and the other puts it in data structure.

Comment: @user3590149 Honestly, that's difficult to say. Partly, I can't say because I can only work with the code provided. While the various forms of persistence are quite varied, I would still say that there is probably _some_ way to separate the specific persistence code into one set of classes generically. Without having more to work with, I can't be any more specific than that.